# Visual Studio wants to load symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So I have been using visual studio for a few years now, but when I got a new computer and installed it it keeps wanting to do things I've never seen it need to do.

All I did was make a regular win32 console app, with the following code (really I didn't add anything drastic)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cin;
    return 0;
}
```

but when I went to run it, I got this

```
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\infPres\Debug\infPres.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'infPres.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Upon googling, I found people with extensive projects they've been working on for years, and I did enable downloading from the server but it's slow and sometimes still doesn't work. When it does, after it's done its download and I go to run the program again it throws that huge block of error and doesn't run.

Comment: Those are not error messages. If you are referring to something else then can you post it too?

Comment: Those are warnings that can be ignored in most cases. With the symbols you can debug inside microsoft dlls. It should be rare to need that. You can enable the symbol server option to have Visual Studio try to download the missing symbols however that will cause some delay when starting every debug session.

Comment: I guess I was freaked out over nothing then, still irks me that I had never seen these before.